# How can I deploy a MERN app? Is a shared server on Hostgator not enough?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-deployment, mern

I currently have a React-only app deployed on Hostgator (I used npm run build then just uploaded the files to cPanel) because it is just a front-end landing page. However, I am planning to add things like logging in and a user dashboard, which will "require" me to use Node.js, Express and MongoDB Atlas.

In this scenario, will it still be possible to deploy the website onto shared hosting on cPanel? It seems to me, from looking online, that this is not possible. In this case, what are my options for other hosting to deploy a MERN stack app on, and what are my options for backend hosting on cPanel that are not Node.js-Express-MongoDB? Do they have their own backend services?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same query and the only solution that I could find was that it is not possible to deploy your MERN app on shared hosting and you need a dedicated server for your applications.

The best and cheaper way to do this is, wrap your application inside a container using Docker and deploy the docker image on a VPS (Virtual Private Server).

Or,

You can also use a separate service for everything that you have to configure yourself and then deploy your app. Kubernetes is the best tool to manage distributed systems.

I hope this helped you.